# Embedding Python thread safe

Tags: python, thread-safety, multicore, embedding, embedded-language

I'm trying to use Python in a module for an analysis software of vehicle bus systems. For this I have to embed  Python in a thread safe manner, since there can be multiple instances of the module witch work independently. I could use a mutex to guard all access to Python and create an unique (python) module for every thread. Obviously this is the easiest way out but comes with the price of not being able to scale across multiple cores. Or I could modify my module to spawn new processes which intern uses Python and connect to them via shared memory. This gives me a performance penalty and costs more time to implement but scales great.

My question: witch one do you think makes more sense? Is there any other way to embed Python thread safe or even in a way that scales over multiple cores.

Kind regards Moritz

edit: I'm using CPython

Comment: It depends on how complex the stuff you're doing in python, but in a general scenario, I would say using multiple interpreters is the right way to go. It would substantially improve the flexibility and scalability (get you around the GIL at the same time) and you wouldn't need per thread modules. I think the result would be much more accessible to other developers on your project and much more general purpose.

Comment: Hi Jagerkin if you post your comment again as Answer I'll probly accept it.

Comment: @Jagerkin: that is exactly what the `multiprocessing` library does. Spawning two Python interpreters at the same time isn't as trivial as it initially sounds, as you will have to care about process/thread synchronization and inter-thread/process communication. The multiprocessing library already does most of the hard work for you, it have multiprocess version of "Queue", "Pipe", "Pool", "shared values" that transparently serializes and deserializes objects over IPC/shared memory, and "Locks" that synchronize over multiple processed, so that you don't have to do them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow-up on my question: I went ahead in implemented it using Processes with intern use Python. A good text why the multiprocessing library does not help can be found here:
http://pkaudio.blogspot.com/2010/04/whey-multiprocessing-doesnt-always-work.html
It was not written by myself but that guy has the same problem as I have. I'm thankful for everybody who tried to help me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're CPU bound, Python can only scale to multiple core using the multiprocessing library. However, if you're I/O bound, then threading is usually sufficient.

If you want easy thread safety, then use Queue for all message passing.

Comment: does the multiprocessing library realy help me? I don't use multiple threads within one Python interpreter, I want to use multiple Python interpreter running in multiple ( C++ ) threads.

Comment: The multiprocessing library can handle spawning subprocess (i.e. it spawns multiple python interpreter) and interprocess-communication (e.g. data sharing, synchronization), and in doing so, avoids the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). I'd suggest on looking at it before trying to spawn multiple interpreters on C++ threads (which will replicate most of what they do in the multiprocessing library).

Comment: Again I don't want sup processes from within Python I want, if at all, to spawn new processes from C. So are you suggesting that I look into the Multiprocessing source code? Or how does the  multiprocessing library help me? I'm not trying to be cocky, but I don't see how your answer helps me.

Comment: You are already seeing the solution before seeing the problem. There is no difference between subprocess spawned by python and subprocess spawned by C. You just need a slightly different way of dividing the tasks, instead of dividing the tasks in C, you now divide tasks in Python. Also, since you're writing for a bus, take extra care to ensure that you are actually using multiprocessing since the library will silently fallback to threading if it thinks it cannot work with the bus' system.